# Proof by mathematical induction; T.B. : Essential discrete mathematics for computer science

Tags: discrete-mathematics, solution-verification, proof-explanation, induction

I am currently going through a discrete math textbook and came across this problem. I couldn't find the solution manual to the book so I don't know if my version of the answer is right or not. I'd love to get some insight into this.

**NOTE:** For anyone that might not know what the Thue–Morse sequence
or Prouhet–Thue–Morse sequence or parity sequence is, it is the binary sequence obtained by starting with $0$ and successively appending the Boolean complement of the sequence obtained thus far.

$$
T_0 = 0\\       
T_1 = 01\\
T_2 = 0110\\
\vdots
$$

Prove the following about the Thue-Morse sequence:

1. For every $n \ge 1$, $T_{2n}$ is a palindrome; that is, a string that reads the same in both directions.
2. For every $n$, if $0$ is replaced by $01$ and $1$ is replaced by $10$ simultaneously everywhere in $T_n$, the result is $T_{n+1}$.

Answer:

1. **Base case:** for $n = 1$, $T_{2 \cdot 1} = 0110 \implies T_2$ is a palindrome.

   **Inductive Hypothesis:** Assume that for some $n > 1$, $T_{2n}$ is a palindrome.

   **Inductive step:**

   - We need to prove $T_{2n+2}$ is also a palindrome.
   - Every iteration of the Thue-Morse sequence either is of the form $01 \dots 10$ or $01 \dots 01$, therefore assume $T_{2n}$ is of the form $01 \dots 10$.
   - $T_{2n+1}$ is $T_{2n}$ appended with the complement of $T_{2n}$:

     $T_{2n+1} = 01 \dots 1010 \dots 01 \implies$ not a palindrome. (i)

     $T_{2n+2}$ is $T_{2n+1}$ appended with the complement of $T_{2n+1}$.

     From (i), $T_{2n+2} = 01 \dots 1010 \dots 0110 \dots 0101 \dots 10 \implies$ palindrome.

   **Conclusion:** Every even iteration of the Thue sequence is a palindrome, i.e., for every even nonnegative $n$, $T_{2n}$ is a palindrome.
2. **Base case:** for $n = 0$, $T_0 = 0$. Applying the process from the statement gives $T_{0+1} = 01$.

   **Inductive hypothesis:** Assume that for some $n > 0$, $T_n$ after applying the process from the statement gives $T_{n+1}$.

   **Inductive step:**

   - We need to prove $T_{n+1}$ becomes $T_{n+2}$ when the statement is applied.
   - We know that the Thue-Morse sequence grows by a factor of $2^n$ and that every even iteration of it is of the form $01 \dots 10$ and every odd iteration of it is of the form $01 \dots 01$.
   - Therefore, if $n+1$ is odd, $T_{n+2}$ has to be a palindrome and twice the size of $T_{n+1}$ and if $n+1$ is even, it wouldn't be a palindrome but it should still be twice the size of $T_{n+1}$.
   - Let's say $n+1$ is odd, then if every $0$ in it becomes $01$ and every $1$ becomes $10$, it gives (written as $\to$): $T_{n+1} = 01......01 \to 0110 \dots 0110$. The term it gives is twice the size of $T_{n+1}$ and is a palindrome, therefore it must be $T_{n+2}$.

   **Conclusion:** If in an iteration of the Thue sequence every $0$ is replaced with $01$ and every $1$ is replaced with $10$, you'd get the next iteration of the sequence.

The part I'm worried about is the "$\dots$" part. I'm worried whether it introduces some ambiguity in the proof and if it does, please tell me if there is any other way to do it. thanks for your time ;)

Comment: Why on earth is *this* question down-voted? Does down-voter care to explain?

Comment: For those that don't know what the Thue sequence is, you should define it. I actually had never heard of it and thought "Thue" was a typo for "The".

Answer (score 1):

For those that don't know what the Thue-Morse sequence is, it is a sequence of $1$s and $0$s where $T_0=0$ and given $T_n$, $T_{n+1}$ is generated by taking the complement of all of the current bits and appending them to the end. The first few elements are $$T_0=0\\T_1=01\\T_2=0110\\\text{etc.}$$
For part 1:

Let's make some simplifying notation. For a sequence $T$, let $\bar T$ be the sequence of complements.

The base case is actually $T_0=T_{2(0)}=0$ which is a palindrome.

For the inductive step, suppose $T_{2k}$ is a palindrome. Then $$T_{2k+1}=T_{2k}\bar T_{2k}$$ and $$T_{2k+2}=T_{2k}\bar T_{2k}\bar T_{2k}T_{2k}$$ which is a palindrome. Since that is true for all $k$, $T_{2n}$ is a palindrome.

For part 2:

Let $R_n$ equal $T_n$ with $0$ replaced by $01$ and $1$ replaced by $10$.

$T_0=0$ and $R_0 = 01 = T_1$ so the claim is true for the base case.

For the inductive part, Suppose $R_k=T_{k+1}$. We know that, by definition,  $$T_{k+1}=T_k\bar T_k$$ so the inductive hypothesis tells us when we replace $0$ by $01$ and $1$ by $10$, we get $$R_{k+1}=T_{k+1}\bar T_{k+1}=T_{k+2}=T_{(k+1)+1}$$

Therefore, $R_n=T_{n+1}$ for all $n$

Comment: Hey, thanks for your input, I'd like to know if there is anything in my answer that might be logically wrong or if my version is not the typical way a proof is written. Because I wanna fix anything I can before I move on with further topics on proofs.

Comment: To be honest, I didn't understand what you were trying to prove until I searched the internet for "Thue sequence". For example, on your third bullet point in part 1 you wrote: "From (i), T2n+2 = 01.....1010.....0110.....0101.....10 -> palindrome." but I don't see (1) anywhere in your proof. It is unnecessary to state that $T_{2n+1}$ is not a palindrome. It can also lead to confusion because the reader may assume that statement is relevant to the proof. Search for examples of inductive proofs on the internet and look at the way they are presented. You'll get better with practice.

Comment: thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

For a correct and simple proof of both claims, see the answer by John Douma. As you asked for feedback about your proof, I will give you that.

The proof for the first claim is correct and well-written, except for the conclusion, where you say that "for every even nonnegative $n$, $T_{2n}$ is a palindrome" instead of "for every $n \ge 1$, $T_{2n}$ is a palindrome". The "even" part was probably because you forgot the evenness already comes from the factor of $2$ in $2n$. The "nonnegative" part would be true as well (i.e. $T_0 = 0$ is palindromic), but it's not what you proved: your base case was $n=1$ and not $n=0$. But those were just minor typos in your conclusion...

However, your proof of the second claim is fundamentally flawed because you cannot conclude that the sequence produced after applying the process from the statement to $T_{n+1}$ is $T_{n+2}$ just because both are palindromic and have the same size. For example, the sequence $01011010$ is palindromic and has $8$ terms while $00100100$ is different but also palindromic and with $8$ terms (these have nothing to do with Thue-Morse but it's just an example). Obviously you also know in your proof that $T_{n+2}$ and the result of applying the process in the statement to $T_{n+1}$ both start and end with $0110$, but they could possibly differ after that (you didn't prove that's impossible).

Your use of "$\dots$", which worried you, is correct and not a problem. In general, it's not bad to use such "$\dots$" if you are careful and sufficiently formal.

Comment: Thanks for your input and also, is it necessary to prove the properties of something that is considered in the proof? for example, the thue sequence does grow by a factor of 2^n and every even iteration is a palindrome. so I thought replacing each 0 or 1 by two characters would double the bit string's length and for the palindrome part I drew from my previous proof.

Comment: @atomic-coder Yes, that is true, but the fact that the process doubles the string length and returns a palindrome (which, btw, is not always true, but dependent of parity) doesn't mean it produces $T_{n+1}$, just because it also has double the length and is palindromic.